# How to Load data in mysql from a text file without creating the table (schema)

Tags: mysql, text-files, load-data-infile

I have a tab separated text file like

a   b   c
1   a   d
2   g   l
3   m   r

I want to load this file in mysql **without creating the table** first. Is there any possibility?

for load data infile, I have to create the table first.

Comment: load where? your question is not clear.

Comment: load in a table, as we do  load data infile '/path/to/file/' into table abc.  but for that, I have to create the table first. I want mysql to create table itself.

Comment: You are looking for an sql file.... first you need to do "create table if not exists bla", and then "insert into bla (a,b,c) values(1,2,3)"  etc..

Comment: The 'S' in MySQL stands for 'structured' - creating the table is defining the structure. Without the table with defined columns, you can't do queries that will produce output that you can trust. There are new apps - Mongo and NoSQL being 2 - that handle unstructured data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't tell to mysql to create automatically your table based on a text file (LOAD DATA INFILE).
The problem is that MySQL can't guess the data type for a column in a file.
I think that to avoid your problem you can use mysqldump to import the table without creating it but what mysql do (as you can see in dump) is CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST.

Comment: This example shows that mysql can guess datatype.  
mysql> create table test.rohabbas select 'abcd', 1245; Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec) Records: 1 Duplicates: 0 Warnings: 0 mysql> show create table test.rohabbas; CREATE TABLE rohabbas ( abcd varchar(4) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 1245 int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci But if it's not available, I think mysql devs are not ready to have this feature included yet :)